# Uploading a video from the android gallery to Firebase Storage with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-image-picker

I am currently working on a **react-native project** where the user can upload a video from his app to **firebase storage**.
The user can either select a video from his library or take a new one directly in the app. I use the `react-native-image-picker` library.
On IOs everything is working as expected. On Android I only managed to upload videos taken directly in the app or **small videos** from the android gallery.

---

If I try to upload videos from the android gallery I encounter **two problems**:

1. Error: [storage/unknown] Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:723 from pid=32673, uid=10226 **requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** or related APIs

This Error occurs if try to upload the video directly with the link I get from the image picker library.

```
   let reference = storage().ref(path);
   let task = reference.putFile(imagePickerResponse.assets[0].uri);
```

I managed to resolve this issue by using the RNFS library. `react-native-fs`

```
   const data = await RNFS.readFile(imagePickerResponse.assets[0].uri, 'base64');
   let task = reference.putString(data, 'base64');
```

But this solution only works for small files. For longer videos the app crashs and I get the following error.

2. **Could not invoke RNFSManager.readFile**:

```
Could not invoke RNFSManager.readFile

null

Failed to allocate a 268435472 byte allocation with 
6291456 free bytes and 116MB until OOM, target 
footprint 152234472, growth limit 268435456
```

Unfortunately I couldnt find any solution online. **Is there any way to upload large video from the Android library to firestore storage?**

---

Image Picker Code

```
export const SelectVideoAction: CameraAction = {
  title: 'Select Video',
  type: 'library',
  options: {
    selectionLimit: 0,
    mediaType: 'video',
  },
};
launchImageLibrary(SelectVideoAction.options, handleResponse);
```

Android Upload Code

```
let reference = storage().ref(targetPath);
let task = reference.putFile(imagePickerResponse.assets[0].uri);
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && fromLibrary) {
  const data = await RNFS.readFile(imagePickerResponse.assets[0].uri, 'base64');
  task = reference.putString(data, 'base64');
}

task
  .then(() => {
     console.log('Image uploaded to the bucket!');
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log('uploading image error => ', e));
```

Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is to split the large video file into chunks, by this way it will not exceed the memory limit of the device and provide a more systematic upload process. Description for the solution sounds pretty good, but it can be very difficult to implement.

There is a package that can do chunk operation: [React Native Chunk Upload](https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-chunk-upload#readme). Does the default version of firebase storage allow chunk upload operations or this package compatible with firebase? I'm not sure but you can give it a try [Uploading large files on web using Firebase](https://medium.com/@at_ishikawa/uploading-large-files-on-web-using-firebase-f3a8a3d62352). You have to change some configurations on firebase side and android permission, which is mentioned in documentation.

At the end of the day, you can consider using more suitable/powerful video storage/streaming service. ([Google Cloud Storage (Multiple Chunk Upload)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#chunked-upload), [Cloudflare Stream](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/uploading-videos/upload-video-file#resumable-uploads-with-tus-for-large-files), Mux)

I realize this isn't a complete answer, but I wanted to share it as it might help you or someone else.